# Parsing a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm getting this JSON response from a server, which has been validated, and I am unable to parse it with my current code. It keeps saying that data is "undefined." Does anybody know what is going wrong?

This is the JSON:

```
   {
       "response": {
           "status": {
               "version": "4.2",
               "code": 0,
               "message": "Success"
           },
           "artists": [
               {
                   "name": "Radiohead",
                   "id": "ARH6W4X1187B99274F"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Radioheadheadhead",
                   "id": "ARKVYRS126DD652B02"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Radiohead Lullabies",
                   "id": "ARHYPRQ11F4C83D230"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Radioheadheadheadheadhead",
                   "id": "ARPMOVZ126DD9A5A25"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Radiohead Tribute - Meeting in the Aisle",
                   "id": "ARVOZQT11E8F5C12BA"
               },
               {
                   "name": "On a Friday",
                   "id": "ARZNOIY1187B989D9C"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Wonky vs. Radiohead",
                   "id": "AR26WWW1187FB40070"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Meeting in the Aisle: a Tribute to the Music of Radiohead",
                   "id": "ARVGJEW11E8F5C0E4E"
               }
           ]
       }
   }
```

This is the code that I wrote that doesn't work. I removed the key value from the code on purpose, as it is supposed to be confidential. Also, I do realize that hotttnesss is spelled wrong. That's the way that they spell it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Project</title>
<script>

var apiUrl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/";
var key = "*****";
var format = "format=json";

function callApi(method, arguments, callBack){
var requestUrl = apiUrl+method+key+format+"&"+arguments;
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("readystatechange",
function() {callBack(request);}, false);
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.send();
}//end try
catch(exception){
alert("Request Failed");
}//end catch
}// end function callApi


function parseData(request){
if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
displayNames(data);
}//end if
}// end function parseData


function displayNames(data){
var listbox = document.getElementById("artists");
listbox.innerHTML = "";
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
var entry = document.createElement("div");
var field = document.createElement("fieldset");
entry.onclick = function() { getGenre(this, this.id);
getHotttnesss(this, this.id);
getSimilar(this, this.id);
getNews(this, this.id);};
entry.number = i;
entry.innerHTML = data[i].name + data[i].id;
field.appendChild(entry);
listbox.appendChild(field);
}//end for
}//end function displayNames


function search(input){
var listbox = document.getElementById("artists");
listbox.innerHTML = "";
callApi("search", "name="+input, parseData);
}//end function search


function getGenre(entry, id){
var requestUrl = apiUrl+"profile"+key+id+"&bucket=genre&"+format;
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("readystatechange",
function() {displayGenre(entry, request);}, false);
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", 
"application/json; charset=utf-8" );
request.send();
}//end try
catch(exception){
alert("Request Failed");
}//end catch
}//end function getGenre


function displayGenre(entry, request){
if(request.readyState==4 && request.status ==200){
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var name = entry.innerHTML;
entry.innerHTML = name +"<br>"+data.genre;
}//end if
}//end function displayGenre


function getHotttnesss(entry, id){
var requestUrl = apiUrl+"hotttnesss"+key+id+"&"+format;
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("readystatechange",
function() {displayHotttnesss(entry, request);}, false);
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", 
"application/json; charset=utf-8" );
request.send();
}//end try
catch(exception){
alert("Request Failed");
}//end catch
}//end function getHotttnesss


function displayHotttnesss(entry, request){
if(request.readyState==4 && request.status ==200){
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var name = entry.innerHTML;
entry.innerHTML = name +"<br>"+data.hotttnesss;
}//end if
}//end function displayHotttnesss


function getSimilar(entry, id){
var requestUrl =apiUrl+"similar"+key+id+"&"+format+"results=3";
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("readystatechange",
function() {displaySimilar(entry, request);}, false);
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", 
"application/json; charset=utf-8" );
request.send();
}//end try
catch(exception){
alert("Request Failed");
}//end catch
}//end function getSimilar


function displaySimilar(entry, request){
if(request.readyState==4 && request.status ==200){
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var name = entry.innerHTML;
entry.innerHTML = name +"<br>"+data.similar;
}//end if
}//end function displaySimilar


function getNews(entry, id){
var requestUrl = apiUrl+"news"+key+id+"&"+format+"&results=3";
try{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("readystatechange",
function() {displayNews(entry, request);}, false);
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", 
"application/json; charset=utf-8" );
request.send();
}//end try
catch(exception){
alert("Request Failed");
}//end catch
}//end function getNews


function displayNews(entry, request){
if(request.readyState==4 && request.status ==200){
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var name = entry.innerHTML;
entry.innerHTML = name +"<br>"+data.news;
}//end if
}//end function displayNews


function start(){
document.getElementById("artistName").addEventListener("keyup",
function(){search(this.value);}, false);
}//end function start


window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<p>Search Artist<input id="artistName">
<div id="artists"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you put `console.log(data)` in between `var data = ...` and `displayNames(...`, what gets printed?

Comment: It's possible that the json is not the issue. Can we see `displayNames`?

Comment: the problem is that display names is passed data, but data is undefined, so it doesn't do anything with the results, and nothing is printed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, my syntax is right, and it SHOULD work. Data remains undefined, and I don't know why.

Comment: @JaylinFrederick Where did you get the JSON in your question from?

Comment: @JaylinFrederick can you show us `displayNames`?

Comment: What happens if you just console.log(request)?

Comment: @JaylinFrederickwelcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: Without more code, I'm assuming there's a syntax error elsewhere in the code :)

Comment: The JSON came from developer.echonest.com. I don't have the rest of the code with me at the moment, but I'll post it when I do.

Comment: When doing the console.log(request) it shows an XMLHttprequest, and everything inside of it looks as it should.
However, when doing the console.log(data), it shows that the JSON is contained in data. Even though it says the JSON is in there, it still prints as undefined.
Now that I have posted the code, perhaps you guys will be able to help me more. I certainly appreciate it.

Comment: Alright I'm intrigued. I signed up for a developer account, and I'm not getting the json you're getting. I'm getting a CORS error response.

Comment: I directly copied all of your html, added my api key, (fixed the url to `?api_key=xxx&format=json&name=xxx`), and got: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=ADFDSFDSAFDSA&format=json&name=a. Origin http://joe.framba.ch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: Oh. They changed my api key. wtf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over an object with `for` (at least not properly).  It seems to me that you want to iterate over `artists`:

```
function displayNames(data) {
    var artists = data.response.artists;
    /* snip */
    entry.innerHTML = artists[i].name + artists[i].id;
    /* snip */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time. I wouldn't have been able to catch that.